# How are IP addresses handled for mobile devices on cellular networks?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm working on a web project at the moment, and during testing with my cell phone to make sure everything executes correctly, I noticed something peculiar. The IP address of my device was different every time I accessed a new web page. For example, it would appear like this in my logs:

02-27-15 9:00:00    x.x.x.137

02-27-15 9:00:10    x.x.x.38

etc.

The mobile device is an Android phone connected via a Verizon 4G network.

Now, to my knowledge, a mobile device is given temporary ownership of a specific IP address for a given timespan, and this ownership is refreshed periodically if the device continues to access new content. But then it occurred to me that my device might be getting bounced between a couple of different towers and it was being given a new IP address over and over again.

I was hoping someone here might be able to provide some clarity on why a device's IP address would change so often, or could point me toward a resource I could read to inform myself.

Comment: `would change so often,`. How often?

Comment: `bounced between a couple of different towers and it was being given a new IP address over and over again.`. Please find out by travelling with your device to the nearest tower.

Comment: @greenapps there's a postback that occurs to move through content on the page, and every time a postback happened there was a different IP address showing up in the logs. The time between clicks could be as low as a few seconds.